# Firebase: Googleservices-info.plist not downloading

Tags: ios, firebase

I've just created a new project in Firebase. I add a new app, and try to download the googleservices-info.plist file, but all I get is 1.json, which contains the text:

```
)]}'
{"status":403,"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

and nothing else. I'm at a complete loss here, can somebody please help me?

Comment: are you downloading the file from the firebase website?

Comment: I had the same problem, causing by I had multiple Google accounts signed in and Google Auth was saying user 2 was logged in and Firebase and I'm permissions was expecting user 1 ;-(

Comment: Ohhhhhh ok. That would explain the problem! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was logged into multiple google accounts at the same time. After logging out of all of my accounts, and back into the only one that I needed, the file downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the project permission will encounter this kind of user permission problem if you signed in multiple Google accounts.

My solution is to sign in the account which owns the firebase project in an incognito window. Then you can download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and set the project permission without any problem.